# Share button inside bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, linkedin-api, popover

I'm having a problem adding the linkedin share button inside the bootstrap popover. 
Inside the popover, nothing happens when I click the button
Out of the popover the button works very well.

How can I fix it?

Here is the HTML

```
  <a data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" class="linkshare" data-container="body" type="button" data-html="true" href="#" id="compartilhar">Compartilhar</a>

  <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
    <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: pt_BR</script>
    <script type="IN/Share" data-url="mydynamicurl"></script>
  </div>
```

And the Jquery

```
  $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
            return $('#popover-content').html();
          }
  });
```

Here is an example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmVLyR

Thanks

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle or provide a live demo? Doesn't seem to work with the code snippets here.

Comment: @miken32 Here is an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmVLyR

Comment: your href="#" change it to href="https://www.linkedin.com/"

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because when you assign the HTML to `#popover-content`, the browser considers you are calling a script that is already loaded: `<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. Look up on your browser's console for a warning like this:

> duplicate in.js loaded, any parameters will be ignored

Check out [my version](https://codepen.io/El_Cacto/pen/rZvpON) of your jsFiddle to see a possible workaround, or **see the following code:**

```
    <!-- Forget about this:
    <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="IN/Share" data-url="mydynamic_url"></script>
    -->        
    <!-- Simplify: -->
    <div class="share">
      <a data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" class="linkshare" data-container="body" type="button" data-html="true" href="#" id="share">Share</a>
    </div>
    <!--/share-->
<script>
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
            html: true,
            content: `<div id="popover-content">
                         <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                test
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>
                                <script type="IN/Share" data-url="mydynamic_url"><\/script>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`
        });
</script>
```

Please confirm if your issue was solved. Cheers!

Comment: I recommend pasting the code in your answer as well since links can expire but the code on stackoverflow will always remain

Comment: @chevybow : Done, thanks for your recommendation. Best regards.